Reynolds transport theorem: formal statement?
Reynolds transport theorem gives a relation:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Omega(t)}fdV = \int_{\Omega(t)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} dV + \int_{\partial\Omega(t)}(\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{n})fdA,$$
for an open and bounded domain $\Omega(t)$ that moves in time $t$, scalar field $f$, and vector field $\mathbf{u}$.
Issue. I can not find a formal statement of the Reynolds transport theorem in the literature. For example, I want to know what are the requirements on the regularity of $\partial\Omega(t)$, $f$, and $\mathbf{u}$.
Question. Can you refer me to a book/paper where the statement is formalized?

Physics Stack Exchange could help you better

My suspicion is that you will have better luck with finding rigorously deep mathematical treatments of the Leibniz integral rule in multiple spatial dimensions---where the Reynolds transport theorem "comes from", so to speak---than by searching for such treatments of the RTT itself.

Note that since the LHS and first term on the right side do not depend on $\bf u$, it cannot be just some vector field as you described it. It must be definable from $\Omega$ and $f$ (up to contributions that do not affect the value of the final integral).
